# I only want to change the docker image name in my terraform template when I pass it in, otherwise I want to keep what is there already

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have this module:

```
resource "google_project_service" "cloud_run" {
  project = var.project_id
  service = "run.googleapis.com"

  disable_dependent_services = true
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = var.service_name
  location = var.default_region
  project  = var.project_id

  template {
    metadata {
      ...
    }

    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/${var.repository_name}@sha256:${var.image_digest}"

        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when we deploy a new version of this service we pass in an image_digest of the docker image we just created.

But when we make general changes to our environment, I don't have easy access to the currently used images in each environment.

Is there a way I can ignore this field when I don't specify an image_digest?

- I've tried referencing the state => not allowed created a circular referece`
- Attempted to put it in a locals block => still a cycle error
- I added a lifecycle block but you can have a non static list there

Answer (score 2):

Terraform is a desired state system, so your configuration must describe what infrastructure ought to exist without reference to the current state.

A typical way to achieve what you've described is to decide on some separate storage location for keeping track of what is the "current image", and then:

- Your process for building images publishes the new image ID to that location each time you release a new image.
- Your Terraform configuration reads the current image ID from that location and uses that as part of the desired state.

This therefore allows you to treat this external storage location as an independently-modifyable part of the desired state, so that you can change its value without changing your Terraform source code.

In AWS a common choice of storage location for this sort of architecture would be AWS SSM Parameter Store, which allows storing arbitrary small configuration values without any need to run a separate database or other data store.

I'm not personally very familar with Google Cloud Platform, so I don't know what is the conventional location to store system parameters there. The closest equivalent I can find for GCP is [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs), which doesn't seem quite right for this situation since the image ID isn't a secret, but I'll use it as an example anyway and then you can switch out for a different data store if you have another one you prefer.

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "image_id" {
  secret_id = "SERVICENAME_image_id"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = var.service_name
  location = var.default_region
  project  = google_project_service.cloud_run.project

  template {
    metadata {
      ...
    }

    spec {
      containers {
        image = data.google_secret_manager_secret.image_id.secret_data

        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use any data store as long as:

- It can store the image ID as a string.
- Your build system (or whatever is responsible for publishing new image versions) can write to it.
- There is a Terraform provider with a data source that can read from it.

With this setup, you can run `terraform apply` whenever you like and if there has not been any new image ID since the last run it will just re-read the same value and notice that nothing changed. But if the image ID has changed since the last run, Terraform will notice that it has changed and propose to update the Cloud Run Service accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you add that input variable as an output variable as well, like this:

```
output "image_digest" {
  value = var.image_digest
}
```

Then any time you need to know what the current image digest in the environment is, you can simply query the Terraform state:

```
terraform output image_digest
```

And if you want to want to run Terraform in one command, using the same value for `image_digest` that is currently being used in the environment:

```
terraform apply -var image_digest=$(terraform output --raw image_digest)
```

Comment: I tried the outputs but because I have two workspaces I have to do something like:

```
output "staging_image_digest" {
  value = module.staging_resources[0].staging_image_digest
}


output "production_image_digest" {
  value = try(module.production_resources[0].production_image_digest, "")
}
```

which would overwrite the others output. Thanks though this is a great solution.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using Terraform Workspaces to manage your separate environments. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/workspaces Instead it sounds like you are inventing some sort of workspace management thing with modules.

Comment: You're probably right, I know enough about terraform to get into trouble. But not enough to get me out. 

Answer (score 1):

Terraform configuration describes the desired state of your infrastructure, its style is declarative. And it works best when used as the source of truth for a piece of infrastructure.

Even though Terraform can import your existing Cloud Run resources (including the image field) into the state with:

```
terraform import ADDRESS ID
```

See [import docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import)
You'll need to initialize the referenced resource in the configuration and use terraform as the source of truth going forward. If the resource is modified outside of Terraform, it'll be rolled back as soon as `terraform apply` is called.

If there are other people modifying this resource, consider storing your Terraform state on the remote backend like Google Cloud Storage or Terraform Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up query-ing GCR with cloud to get the digest by image tag like this:

```
gcloud container images describe gcr.io/project-id/image-name:latest --format='get(image_summary.digest)'
```

Comment: In this case, I think a data source can be used. I posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data sources in Terraform can retrieve data from providers like Google Cloud including Google Cloud Registry GCR. That includes image URL which can be used in your "google_cloud_run_service" resource:

```
data "google_container_registry_image" "image_x" {
  name = "image-name-here"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = var.service_name
  location = var.default_region
  project  = var.project_id

  template {
    metadata {
      ...
    }

    spec {
      containers {
        image = data.google_container_registry_image.image_x.image_url

        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See docs for [google_container_registry_image](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/container_registry_image)